# before_destroy callback on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback

I want to use before_destroy callback in my rails app. I want to use it because I use it on notification. But how can I use before_destroy?

I have my code here for `before_save` and `after_save` but I don't know what will I do for `before_destroy`.

```
class Record < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Callbacks
  before_save {
    @is_new_record = self.new_record? if self.new_record?
  }

  after_save {
    action = @is_new_record ? 'created' : 'updated'
    Notification.publish_notification(self, action)
  }

  ...
  #Some stuffs here
```

**UPDATE**

---

Actually, I want to save logs for my table `Notification` just like when creating new record.
Like,

`User One created new Record.`

So I want to save on notification before I destroy a record. Just like.

`User One destroy a record.`

Just like that.

Please help me.

Comment: What do you want to do before deleting a record?

Comment: I don't know what's exactly your problem?

Comment: I updated the question for further explanation.

Comment: Is "User One" supposed to have the id of the current user?

Answer (score 4):

I prefer to use methods instead of the anonymous blocks. I would handle this as follows:

```
class Record < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_save :remember_new_record
  after_save  :write_save_notification
  before_destroy :write_destroy_notification

  # ... the rest of your class ...

  private

    def remember_new_record
      @is_new_record = self.new_record? 
    end

    def write_save_notification 
      action = @is_new_record ? 'created' : 'updated'
      Notification.publish_notification(self, action)
    end

    def write_destroy_notification
      Notification.publish_notification(self, 'destroy')
    end
  end
```

So it is simple as that, unless you ment something else?